Why query_engine.query can plot but agent.query cannot (llamindex)
fault_count_engine = PandasQueryEngine(df=df, verbose=True)

query_engine_tools = [
    QueryEngineTool(
    query_engine=fault_count_engine,
    metadata=ToolMetadata(
        name="fault_count_engine",
        description="Provides information about fault counts. "
                    "Use a detailed tabular question as input to the tool.",
    ),
)
    
]

Initialize ReAct agent
agent = ReActAgent.from_tools(query_engine_tools, llm=llm, verbose=True)

from IPython.display import Markdown, display
response = agent.query(
    "Plot the graph for fault count of all groups?",
)
display(Markdown(f"<b>{response}</b>"))

The above code cannot plot the bar graph, instead, it returns a table of the count of each group.
However, the below code gives the bar chart directly.
query_engine = PandasQueryEngine(df=df, verbose=True)
response = query_engine.query(
    "Plot the graph for fault count of all groups?",
)

I would like to know the reason why the agent cannot plot. Besides, if I insist to use agent method, how can I modify it to plot the chart?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. You forgot to add your programming language as a tag (I've added Python, given the Pandas references). Also, read our guide on formatting. Not formatting code as code makes it difficult to read and making all text bold and huge just hurts peoples eyes, resulting in drive-by downvotes and most people otherwise ignoring your post. Don't do that.
